# set root view controller in main storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

[image: main.storyboard]

so i have this storyboard and i want the user to be shown the login view controller if he is not logged in or the tab view controller otherwise.
this is my code inside the app delegate :

`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:                                       [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
    
    // check user
    let authListener = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
        if user != nil {
            print("USER IS NOT NIL")
            userService.observeUserProfile(uid: user!.uid) { userProfile in
                userService.currentUserProfile = userProfile
            }
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarVC") as! UITabBarController
            self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            self.window?.rootViewController = vc
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            
        } else {
            print("USER IS NIL")
            userService.currentUserProfile = nil
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstVC") as! UIViewController
            vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            self.window?.rootViewController = vc
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
}
```

`
My problem is that if the user is not logged it looks like this:

[image: the login screen]

As you can see the view is not full screen even though i specified that in the app delegate so the user can simply dismiss it and enter the main screen. Also in the tab view controller i have the main screen with a playing video and the login screen also has a playing video in the background and both videos are played at the same time XD .Any tips would be welcome.

Comment: One of the issues I can spot right away is that your current user detection logic is asynchronous, which means it takes time to complete... Even if this not the root of your problem, it is definitely something that you may consider changing.

Comment: thanks, i now realise why i had some issues.. how can i make it synchronous?

Comment: There is no single "right" answer to this as it depends on a lot of factors. A common approach is to attempt an "auto-login", show some form of a loading indicator, and then decide when you get a response from your authentication service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change storyboard--> viewcontroller---> attribute inspector---> change presentation from Automatic to Full Screen

Answer (score 1):

```
    let nav = UINavigationController()
    nav.navigationBar.isHidden = true

    //your Controller 
    let first = Router.shared.splashVC()
    let third = Router.shared.CustomTabbarVC()

    third.selectedIndex = 0

    //add multiple controller in array 

    nav.viewControllers = [first,third]
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = nav
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Answer (score 0):

**First Select all ViewController and change presentation mode Automatic from Full Screen in Simulated Metrics.**

[image]

**Added UINavigationController in rootViewController**

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarVC") as! UITabBarController
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
vc.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```